# регулярное выражение для удаления одинаковых слов в строчках?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

возможно ли с помощью регулярного выражения очистить строчки от повтороений

пример

```
Flamingosis - Love Me In The Evening # //cool //summ //cool  
See-I - Queen Of Sheba # //good //hop //good //hop  
Amati, Touf - Purple Train # //good //glam //strange  //good
```

как мы видимим, после решётки значения повторяются
можно ли убрать дубли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить на пустоту:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)
(//\s+)(?=//)
```

А затем  `+` на  .

Comment: Flamingosis - Love Me In The Evening # ////s+?=// //summ //cool    
See-I - Queen Of Sheba # ////s+?=// ////s+?=// //good //hop    
Amati, Touf - Purple Train # ////s+?=// //glam //strange  //good    

после первой замены вот так должно быть?

Comment: в целом не проблема конечно, в макросе запишу замены ////s+?=// на пустоту и всё... Спасибо!

Comment: Первая замена `(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)` на пустоту, вторая замена `(//\s+)(?=//)` на пустоту, третья замена - с пробелами.