# попогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

```
Booker T. & The MG's - Let's Go Get Stoned #{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Booker T. & The MG's - You Keep Me Hanging On #{C}Brian Holland, {L}Brian Holland,{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Boy George - I Asked For Love #{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Boy George - Just Ain't Enough #{L}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier, {L}Lamont Dozier
```

во второй части повторяются значения
как убрать повторения?

они могут идит как подряд, так и хаотично
при этом левая часть, до решётки, - должна оставаться неизменной...

Comment: Та же идея, что в первом вопросе. В чём проблема?

Comment: почему-то плывёт результат... а я ещё не натаскался...

Comment: {C} Lamont Dozier
{L} Lamont Dozier
не считаются дублями!

Comment: Мне кажется, это еще одна задача где исключительно регулярными выражениями не решить дело. Регулярки могут помочь найти, вытащить группы текста, но закончить обработку нужно на языке програмирования (ЯП), чем регулярки не являются. Например, регулярки могут найти и вытащить `{L}Lamont Dozier`, `{C}Lamont Dozier` и `{L}Lamont Dozier`, но именно ЯП уберет дубликаты и заменит текст после `#` на новый

Comment: дубли только когда полностью совпадает... и буква в скобках, и то что после неё..

Comment: мне кажется тут не сильно сложнее чем вот тут у меня же...https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062177/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: пусть не регуляркой одной, пусть их будет три.. записать в макрос и всё...
просто я ещё не полностью их прочувствовал...

Comment: может если после решётки поставить запятую с пробелом, будет прощё подчинить всё логике?

Comment: по поводу затыкания дырок)) мне в целом - это действие - это край того что нужно, финальный штрих.. и так не хочется из-за этого погружаться в программирование, там где я пока что полный ноль.... в том что ниже, и ничерта не понимаю (

Comment: В поле найти `(\{[A-Z]\}[A-z ]+)(.*)(\1)[, ]{0,}`, в поле Заменить на `\1\2`, проверьте все ли так. Режим поиска `Регуляр. выражен.` без установленной галочки `и новые строки`

Comment: красота, работает!

Comment: Разберись уже как регулярками пользоваться. Одни и те же вопросы постоянно.

Comment: я пытаюсь... многое уже понял.. но это сразу не даётся! нет у меня программистского прошлого..я думал данный сайт отчасти и для помощи таким как я

Comment: я вот сколько не читаю.. пока никак не могу понять как квадратные скобки работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В поле **найти**:

```
(\{[A-Z]\}[A-z ]+)(.*)(\1)[, ]{0,}
```

в поле **Заменить на**

```
 \1\2
```

Режим поиска: **Регуляр. выражен.** без установленной галочки "**и новые строки**"

---

Увидел в комментариях что не понятна специфика работы, попробую на данном примере объяснить простыми словами как собирать регулярные выражения самому.
Приступим шаблон поиска:
`(\{[A-Z]\}[A-z ]+)(.*)(\1)[, ]{0,}`

`\{[A-Z]\}` - данный блок говорит о том, что у нас может быть любая большая буква в диапазоне от `A` до `Z` стоящая между фигурными скобками `\{Любая буква\}`, фигурные скобки являются спецсимволами регулярных выражений, поэтому их нужно экранировать символом `\`

`[A-z ]+` - далее после первого совпадения должно произойти второе, которое означает любой буквенный символ в диапазоне от `A` до `Z` и от `a` до `z` и пробел, так как он тоже присутствует в шаблоне. Символ плюс`+` - это квантификатор, говорит он нашему шаблону о том что символы заданные в скобка перед ним могут повторятся от 1 до любого количества раз и захват оканчивается перед символом не описываемым в шаблоне, в нашем случае это любой символ кроме латинских букв и пробелов.

`(\{[A-Z]\}[A-z ]+)` - круглые скобки представляют собой группу захвата, в данном выражении она первая группа, при ее вызове `\1` или `$1` будут подставлены та последовательность символов, которые захватили описанные внутри шаблоны.

`(.*)` - Вторая группа `\2` или `$2` из любого количества любых символов символов, где точка`.` любой символ, а звездочка`*` - квантификатор.

`(\1)` - Это третья группа как в нее как раз попадает набор символов полученный в группе 1. На самом деле обозначать группу тут не нужно, можно было указать \1 без фигурных скобок.

`[, ]{0,}` - и наконец пробел или знак запятой, с квантификатором `{0,}` - указывающий возможность отсутствия совпадения, до любого количества запятых и пробелов в любом порядке.

---

Т.е. данный шаблон ищет строки содержащие повторяющиеся последовательности символов и заменяет их на данные выбранные в 1 и 2 группах, при этом не возвращая остальные символы.

---

Стоит учесть, что при составлении регулярного выражения, я опирался на наличие фигурных скобок `{буква}`, и никак не привязывался к выбору текста за решеткой или перед и в некоторых случаях оно может вести себя не правильно.

Comment: думаю перечитав пару раз смогу усвоить!! моё почтение)

Comment: даже понял))) гениально

Comment: а где можно дополнительно про третью группу почитать? я в целом смог по аналогии сам уже подобную задачку решить, но мне бы хотелось узнать побольше о том как (\1) работает

Comment: пардон... вроде бы нашёл сам!

Comment: @МишаХитч третья группа в данном случае не обязательна, мы ее **не** используем дальше, т.е. если бы шаблон замены был к примеру `оригинал -\1\2, а это дубль \3`, тогда бы был смысл ее в скобки добавлять. А отвечая на вопрос, тот набор символов определенный в первой группе`шаблон в первых скобках` будет подставлен вместо \1, т.е. это уже не шаблон, а четкий набор символов. К примеру если первой группой мы выбрали в строке `{C}Lamont Dozier`, то при вызове \1 будут поставлены эти же символы `{C}Lamont Dozier`

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода на `python 3`, что используя регулярные выражения сделает замену текста:

```py
import re

text = """
Booker T. & The MG's - Let's Go Get Stoned #{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Booker T. & The MG's - You Keep Me Hanging On #{C}Brian Holland, {L}Brian Holland,{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Boy George - I Asked For Love #{C}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier  
Boy George - Just Ain't Enough #{L}Lamont Dozier, {C}Lamont Dozier, {L}Lamont Dozier  
"""

def replace_func(match: re.Match):
    # Получаем список слов, через разделение по запятой.
    # Пример: ['{C}Lamont Dozier', ' {C}Lamont Dozier  ']
    words = match.group(1).split(',')

    # Убираем пробелы слева и справа от слов и удаляем дубликаты через множество.
    # Пример: {'{C}Lamont Dozier'}
    words = set(word.strip() for word in words)

    # Возвращаем строку на замену, в которой не будет повторов
    return '#' + ', '.join(words)

new_text = re.sub(r'#(.+?)$', replace_func, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
Booker T. & The MG's - Let's Go Get Stoned #{C}Lamont Dozier
Booker T. & The MG's - You Keep Me Hanging On #{C}Lamont Dozier, {L}Brian Holland, {C}Brian Holland
Boy George - I Asked For Love #{C}Lamont Dozier
Boy George - Just Ain't Enough #{C}Lamont Dozier, {L}Lamont Dozier
```

---

**PS.**

Если бы у вас был файл, в котором нужно было сделать замену, то:

```py
with open('<file_name>.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# Код с регуляркой, что выше

with open('<file_name>.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

Регулярки хороши, но затыкать ими все дырки алгоритма приведет к проблеме поддерживания их, т.к. известно, что регулярки часто проще заново написать, чем прочитать или исправить.

Comment: спасибо большое